# Magento 2 Get Order ID before sending to Payment Gateway in Controller?

Tags: controller, magento2

I wanted do know how to get order id of currently placed order after redirecting to a controller
I need this becaue after sending the browser to payment gateway I need to know which Order ID to set to completed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all to do this you need to do a lot of work. There isn't a simple way to do it.

When you are in your custom gatewway payments files you need to find:

**app/code/Magento/sample_gateway/view/payment/method-renderer/sample_getway.js**

This file is your js script that controls all transaction doing in your view, even your ajax.

Keep this file, we are going to need it later.

Next, we need to create a controller for new people on magento. This is the easiest way to create php files, if you don't know how to create a controller. I suggest you visit this link (http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) this links is for a customer module, I really suggest yo go do it and control all your external logic from here.

Your controller should look like this

```
    <?php
namespace your_module\CallBacks\Controller\Payu;


use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Success extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {



        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

        $result = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();

        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        //$orderId=$order->getEntityId();
        $order->getIncrementId();

        $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
        $themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('z_payu_tx');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ". $themeTable . 
                " (orderid, date, state_pol,customer_number) 
                VALUES 
                ('".$order->getIncrementId()."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','NEW','".$customerId."')";

        try{

            $connection->query($sql);

            $resultData = [
                'orderId' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'msg_status' => true,
            ];

        }catch(\Exception $e){

            $resultData = [
                'orderId' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'msg_status' => false,
            ];
        }


        return $result->setData($resultData);


    }

}
```

At this point, this controller can just get the customer id of the current order and you can get the order number. If your controller is named getOrderNumber.php you can try this just (your site/CallBacks/Controller/Payu/getOrderNumber).

This way you can try all your code in magento 2 logic, its really useful.

This can be done with an observer, but for real use, you can't debug as easy as your own php. Remember, if you want developer mod you need to run in your command line php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer.

Now that you have your controller, you need your js file to do a ajax call in certain point of the process.

The sample_getway.js that we found before, we need to understand that this is a override of main magento file for processing orders. Now we can use and override any function that magento2 has.

```
{

    ....

},
setOrder: function() {

            // this.getOrderId();
            this.placeOrder();



        },
        afterPlaceOrder: function (data, event) {
          if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }


          this.getOrderId();

        },
        getOrderId: function () {


              var _url = urlBuilder.build("callbacks/Payu/Success");
              var merchantId = "508029";
              var ApiKey = "4Vj8eK4rloUd272L48hsrarnUA";
              var refCode = "";
              var amount = this.getTotalAmount();
              var currency = this.getCurrency();
              var signatureKey = "";

              var param = 'ajax=1';
              jQuery.ajax({
                  showLoader: true,
                  url: _url,
                  data: param,
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json'
              }).done(function (data) {
                  if(data.msg_status){
                    refCode = data.orderId;

                    var unCode = ApiKey+"~"+merchantId+"~"+refCode+"~"+amount+"~"+currency;
                    signatureKey= hex_md5(ApiKey+"~"+merchantId+"~"+refCode+"~"+amount+"~"+currency);
                    document.getElementById("refCodeInput").value = refCode
                    document.getElementById("signatureValue").value = signatureKey;

                    document.getElementById("payuForm").submit();
                    return;
                  }else{

                    alert("Se ha presentado un error, porfavor intentelo más tarde")

                  }
              }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);

                alert(textStatus);
                alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
                alert(textStatus);

              });

        },
        getResponseUrl: function(){

          return urlBuilder.build("checkout/onepage/success");

        },
        getconfirmPageUrl: function(){

          return urlBuilder.build("callbacks/Payu/confirmPage");

        },


    ....

},
```

if you look, we have some extra function and some override functions, the setOrder, afterPlaceOrder, this.placeOrder().

setOrder-> this is the function associated to my button in html

app/code/Magento/sample_gateway/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html

```
<input type="image" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.payulatam.com/img-secure-2015/boton_pagar_mediano.png" data-bind="click: setOrder"/>
```

This is just a click action and it js function.

this.placeOrder()-> this is the magic of this part, this is the way you let magento2 create the order (Frameworks utilities), now you need to know when this process end to do anything else, in my case I need to fill a form whit certain values, so I need to stop de auto redirecting to keep the info and redirect to the payment company, for this we have an wonderful function

afterPlaceOrder -> let you do any action after order is placed, at this point you can do whatever you want, redirect to home, to payment company, etc.

this is tricky `redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,` is the variable that let you auto redirect or not, in my case I need different url so I redirect in getOrderId who is called by afterPlaceOrder.

If you wanna try this you need to deactivate a function who clean the car just after success call just comment $session->clearQuote() and you just can call the controller for testing after creating order.

```
    namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        //$session->clearQuote(); //This stop clear the cart.
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you! A little late because was having a hard time understanding magento2.

Comment: Please do not execute raw SQL statements and do not use business logic inside controllers. Instead delegate it to specific class like PaymentProcessor and here use OrderRepositoryInterface to obtain Order by id.